# How to compute sum of squares of two largest numbers out of three in python

Tags: python

Coming from C/Java background, I wrote python program(shown below) for the below question, which will not compile, becasue, ?:(ternary operator) is not available in python.

```
Write a function that takes three positive numbers and returns the sum of the squares of the two largest numbers. Use only a single expression for the body of the function:
```

---

```
def two_of_three(a, b, c):
    """Return x*x + y*y, where x and y are the two largest of a, b, c.

    >>> two_of_three(1, 2, 3)
    13
    >>> two_of_three(5, 3, 1)
    34
    >>> two_of_three(10, 2, 8)
    164
    >>> two_of_three(5, 5, 5)
    50
    """
    return ((a>b)? 
                ((b>c)?(a*a+b*b):(a*a+c*c))
                :
                ((a>c)?(a*a+b*b):(c*c+b*b))
                )
```

My question:

Can you please let me know an alternate approach for writing a single expression?

Comment: BTW, i see many sum of squares queries in SO, which are not relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
def two_of_three(a,b,c):
    return a**2+b**2+c**2-min([a,b,c])**2
```

Comment: You can just do `min(a, b, c)`.

Comment: @gregkow this is pure mathematics, if we are school pass out. But I always struggle in taking an approach to solve the problem. approach mean, i mostly fail to decide, when to use math, when to use proper DS&algo to resolve the logic.

Comment: @gregkow python is not free-form langugae to write, but no clue, why i see this error,     `return a**2+b**2+c**2-min(a,b,c)**2
                                                       
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` ERROR IS EXACTLY AT LAST OPERAND(2) OF THE EXPRESSION POINTING WITH CARAT SYMBOL

Answer (score 1):

```
def Largest_Square_Two(a, b, c):
    return max(a*a+b*b, b*b+c*c, c*c+a*a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_of_three(a,b,c):
    return (a*a+b*b if a>c<b else
            c*c+a*a if c>b<a else
            b*b+c*c)
```

Comment: i think if-else is a control statement, but not expression

Comment: I don't think this works fine for 5, 2, 2. Should check also for equality.

Comment: This doesnt deserve a downvote. +1. This is actually a very readable and direct translation of exactly what the author wanted. It does not sort arrays, or finds the minimum values, and is probably the fastest implementation. Not sure why anyone would downvote this one!!

Comment: @ssm, I downvoted it, because in its current form it is buggy. See my comment above. I will be happy to undownvote it, if it will be edited to use <= instead of < wherever it is needed.

Comment: Maybe `((a*a+b*b if b>c else a*a+c*c) if a>b else (a*a+b*b if a>c else  b*b+c*c))` is the more direct translation of the original C code.

Answer (score -1):

```
def two_of_three(a,b,c):
    num1 = max(a,b)
    num2 = max(b,c)
    if num1==num2:
        num1 = max(a,c)

    return num1**2 + num2**2
```

Comment: This is not a single expression as asked for by OP.